# Пропало динамичное выделение текста в Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text

Пару дней назад я что-то нажал в саблайме и у меня пропало динамичное выделение текста, теперь выделение происходит только после того, как я отпускаю ЛКМ. Никаких хоткеев для этого я не нашел. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Нажмите на *view*, потом выберите категорию *syntax*, и выберите ваш код программирования.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).